# Get images by custom field

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to display all images that have a certain custom field from [the types plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) set to `true`. It would also work to filter them by `post_content` or `post_excerpt` but none of my attempts have worked so far.

```
<?
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_content' => 'foo',
    'numberposts' => -1
  );
?>

<? print_r(get_posts($args)); ?>
```

This get's *all* images allthough only *one* has the post_content `foo`. My attempt to use `WP_Query` failed miserably as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The reason why your code returns all images is because `get_posts` doesn't have a `post_content` parameter, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WP_Query method :**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',        
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am presuming that the reason why you failed with WP_Query is due to the following condition.

Codex states : *The default WP_Query sets 'post_status'=>'publish', but attachments default to 'post_status'=>'inherit' so you'll need to explicitly set post_status to 'inherit' or 'any' as well.*

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

**`get_posts` method :**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'meta_key' => 'custom-field',
    'meta_value' => 'custom value',
    'numberposts' => -1
);

print_r(get_posts($args));
```

The only draw back with this method is that the `meta_value` needs to exactly match what was entered in the custom field. If you still like to use `get_posts` then use the `meta_query` as shown in WP_Query example above.

Comment: thanks anand, this led me in the right direction. I won't upvote since you don't have the unsung hero badge yet :)